# SharePoint Hosted App not working. App domain issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-hosted-app, domain

I followed this [link](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) to configure the app domain for SharePoint 2013.

While configuring the DNS we followed below steps:

- First created zone: owapps.com
- Alias Name: *
- FQDN: *.owapps.com
- FQDN for target host: mycompany.com

**Issue:**

After configuring the Domain name in our organization domain server, while using the owapps.com domain name in SP Central Admin “in configure app url”
the app does not work on server or the local machine.

But when we put the Domain name as mycompany.com the App works on server but it does not work on local machine.

> The error message is “The site cannot be reached”

I am hindering to find the correct solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the site in the Trusted site in the internet option settings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FQDN for target host` must point to the FQDN of your SharePoint-Server instead of your current AD-Domain.

Example: `sharepoint.mycompany.com`

[image: CNAME Configuration]

Microsoft-Documentation: [Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint)